# Are PostMessage calls safe to a handle that's 0?

Tags: delphi, postmessage

I have a datamodule with a HWND handle that receives PostMessage calls.

The handle is allocated in the DataModuleCreate like this (TTNONVISUAL is *not* defined):

```
{$IFNDEF TTNONVISUAL}
FHWND := AllocateHWND(WindProc);
{$ELSE}
FHWND := 0;
{$ENDIF}
```

The data module is also used in a non-visual program where TTNONVISUAL *is* defined.

The WindProc in the datamodule is enclosed in {$IFNDEF TTNONVISUAL}, so in the non-visual program there is no WindProc and FHWND=0

In that program, will it be safe to do PostMessage calls to this 0 handle?

Note: The PostMessage does not send any additional data:
PostMessage(FHWND,WM_SYNC_PROGRESS,0,0)
and WM_SYNC_PROGRESS is WM_USER + 111 and there are no other WM_SYNC_PROGRESS handlers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

[When passing NULL for a handle, which doesn't refer to variant Null, but actually the value `0`]:

> The function behaves like a call to PostThreadMessage with the
>   dwThreadId parameter set to the identifier of the current thread.

So, it has a distinct meaning to post messages to `0`, and you should not just allow that if you actually want to fire messages into oblivion. If that's the case, you'd rather check if the handle is `0` and not post the message at all.

Note, though, that is it perfectly legit to create a window, even in a non-visual application. Handles like this are for sending messages to. They don't necessarily point to a *visible* window. Actually, that is just what [AllocateHWND](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_AllocateHWnd.html) is for. It is used for non visual controls (like TTimer) that need to be able to recieve messages after all.

Comment: You may want to create your own wrapper function to do that, winstead of putting a lot of ifs in many places in your code.